# How to automatically mark emails as unread if they are older than 3 days and have not been replied to or forwarded?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to keep track of emails that I haven't dealt with.

I would like to mark any email that is older than 3 days as unread but only if the email hasn't been replied to or forwarded.

I managed to cobble together the script below from some ones found online. It did the date detection but not the replied status. This resulted in it marking everything older than 3 days as unread.

I haven't added the forwarded status and I would like to add a variable for emails that have attachments with a specific file name but I am trying to get it working with just replies first.

I'm running Outlook 365.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub HelpMeRemember()

    Dim objInbox As Folder
    
    Dim objInboxItems As Items
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set objInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print objInbox.Name
    
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
    objInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    
    For i = objInboxItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    
        If TypeOf objInboxItems(i) Is MailItem Then
        
            With objInboxItems(i)
                If .PropertyAccessor <> 102 And .ReceivedTime < Date - 3 Then
                    
                    .UnRead = True
                    .Save
                    
                    'Debug.Print "Not replied to."
                    'Debug.Print "Older mail."
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .Subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
            
                ElseIf .PropertyAccessor = 102 Then
                
                    'Debug.Print "Reply Sent."
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .Subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                ElseIf .ReceivedTime > Date - 3 Then
                
                    'Debug.Print "Newer mail."
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .Subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
            
                    Exit For    ' Stop when newer mail encountered.
                    
                End If
                
            End With
            
        Else
        
            Debug.Print "Non-mailitem ignored."
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
objInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    
For i = objInboxItems.Count To 1 Step -
   If TypeOf objInboxItems(i) Is MailItem Then
```

Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class instead. They allows getting items that correspond to your conditions, so you could iterate over items found only. Read more about these items in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

As soon as you find items you may check the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` property value, or just can add one more condition to the search criteria. If that property is not set then you have never replied or forwarded the original email. The `Replied mail` flag has the following value - 0x00000105. And the `Forwarded mail` has the following meaning - 0x00000106.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how you could apply`.PropertyAcessor`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub HelpMeRemember()

    Dim objInbox As Folder
    
    Dim objInboxItems As Items
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim intLastVerb As Long
    
    Set objInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print objInbox.name
    
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
    objInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    
    For i = objInboxItems.count To 1 Step -1
    
        If TypeOf objInboxItems(i) Is mailItem Then
            
            With objInboxItems(i)
            
                Debug.Print "Subject: " & .subject

                intLastVerb = .propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
    
                Debug.Print intLastVerb
                Debug.Print .ReceivedTime
                Debug.Print Date - 3
                
                ' Source unknown
                ' 102 "Reply to Sender"
                ' 103 "Reply to All"
                ' 104 "Forward"
                ' 108 "Reply to Forward"
                
                If .ReceivedTime > Date - 3 Then
                
                    Debug.Print "Newer mail."
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
            
                    Exit For    ' Stop when newer mail encountered.
                    
                ElseIf intLastVerb = 102 Then
                    Debug.Print "Reply to Sender"
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                ElseIf intLastVerb = 103 Then
                    Debug.Print "Reply to All"
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                ElseIf intLastVerb = 104 Then
                    Debug.Print "Forward"
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                ElseIf intLastVerb = 108 Then
                    Debug.Print "Reply to Forward"
                    'Debug.Print " Subject: " & .subject
                    'Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                Else
                    .UnRead = True
                    '.Save  ' If necessary
                    
                End If
                
            End With
            
        Else
        
            Debug.Print "Non-mailitem ignored."
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```

You could Restrict by date and by mailitem to apply code to older mail only. Since this code limits processing to the applicable items already there would probably be little change in efficiency.